# How to add static css to node js app by express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js app with a static css file. When I create a middleware and call the css file, it is geeting an error as follows:

**Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/files/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**

**Here is my app.js file**

```
var express = require ('express');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/files', express.static('/files'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>New style</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use URL : http://localhost:3000/files/style.css

Display "**Cannot GET /files/style.css**" and when checking in the console's network tab, it says styles.css not found. This happens when I add static javascript files too.

**I also tried this with follows**

```
app.use('/files', express.static(__dirname + '/files'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/files'));
app.use(express.static('files'));
```

and none of them has worked so far.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to get file from `files/files/files/style.css`

Try code below:

**NodeJs:**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'files')));
```

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

Comment: @David Johns  I created [worked example](https://github.com/Mestafor/example-express-static-folder/tree/master) on github. Please check it. I hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hey, I did that but I got a problem in live, I had host this with apache without the port specified in server.js For this I am using .htaccess to forward it to specified url, that gives 404 for the static files.